# pyodbc error when Access field name contains diacritics

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc python module.

when I use `SELECT = "SELECT k.Poznámka as poznamka from karta as k"` I get error

Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Problem is with name "Poznámka" and "á" in it. When I use the same select with field title without diacritics for example k.Name everything works.

What with this please?

Comment: This is very unclear. Remember we have no idea what are you talking about.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the following code worked for me without errors:

```python
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT k.Poznámka as poznamka from karta as k")
while 1:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print row.poznamka
cnxn.close()
```

### Edit

With my Python source file encoded as UTF-8 the following worked for me:

```python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = u"SELECT k.Poznámka as poznamka from karta as k"
cursor.execute(sql.encode('cp1252'))
while 1:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print row.poznamka
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: yeeees, that must be my issue. I am using utf-8 in python file but it seems my access is cp1252. please, any advice how should I edit my sql query to be able to handle this?

Comment: @peter I had just updated my answer when your comment appeared.

Comment: thank you. But I can't change coding for whole python script. Is there any chance how to change it for this one SELECT only? I tried u'Poznámka'.encoding('cp1252') directly in SELECT it didn't help.

Comment: Gord, Thank you for your effort. But error "Too few parameters. Expected 1..." still persists

Comment: @peter What can I say? My script works for me. You can download it [here](http://wikisend.com/download/404284/gordTest.zip) and see if it contains some magic goodness that is not apparent to me.